# Validating a value when button is pressed before passing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am new to React and I am a little bit confused on how to validate a value before passing it to the partialRefund function I have.

I am trying to set a simple validation to make sure the value is not empty and numeric before passing it to the partialRefund function.

The first line is the code I currently have. The second line is the code I am trying to write for the validation but it is not working.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

```
//Current code
     {partialRefundSelected ? <div> <input id={`partial_refund_${order_id}`} type='text'/> <button onClick={() =>  partialRefund(order_deets_obj,"partialRefund",document.getElementById('partial_refund_'+order_id).value)}> Refund Order  </button> </div> : ""}



//Code I am trying to use 
    {partialRefundSelected ? <div> <input id={`partial_refund_${order_id}`} type='text'/> <button onClick={(validateValue(document.getElementById('partial_refund_'+order_id).value)) =>  partialRefund(order_deets_obj,"partialRefund",document.getElementById('partial_refund_'+order_id).value)}> Refund Order  </button> </div> : ""}
```

On the second line i am trying to pass a function that will validate the value and the pass it to the partialRefund function.  But it doesnt seem to be working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the validation in the `onClick` callback if you add curly brackets around the `parttialRefund` call.

```
export default function App() {
  const partialRefundSelected = true;
  const order_id = 1;
  const order_deets_obj = { deets: "good deets" };

  const partialRefund = (deets, someString, someValue) => {
    console.log(deets, someString, someValue);
  };

  return partialRefundSelected ? (
    <div>
      <input id={`partial_refund_${order_id}`} type="text" />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const value = document.getElementById("partial_refund_" + order_id)
            .value;

          // Do validation here
          if (value === "I LOVE CATS") {
            partialRefund(order_deets_obj, "partialRefund", value);
          }
        }}
      >
        Refund Order
      </button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    ""
  );
}
```

While this is an option in react, I would suggest making your input a [Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). This would allow you to keep the input's text in state instead of needing to pull the text off of the element after a click. Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-mclaren-t8riw?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
{
   partialRefundSelected ? 
   <div> 
      <input id={`partial_refund_${order_id}`} type='text'/> 
     <button onClick={() => {
          const validatedValue=validateValue(document.getElementById('partial_refund_'+order_id).value));
    
       partialRefund(order_deets_obj,"partialRefund",validatedValue);
}}> Refund Order  
    </button> 
</div> :
 ""}
```